# How to store field data in a file instead of the db?

Tags: 7, entities, files

So far, I found two decent options for storing field in a file:

1. using node hooks to store data in a filefield, and process it on node view
2. theoretically, the best would be to use file storage as a backend, but is there a module for field file storage instead of field sql storage?

My use case is a field that does not change, but mysql backup is very slow because there are 600 000 nodes with it. I also do not need to query this field, just display it. With file storage I can do incremental backup which is lightyears more efficient.

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet's going to be using the [MongoDB](https://www.drupal.org/project/mongodb) module, I think ... Here is a quote about it (from the module's project page):

> ... is a collection of several modules which allow sites to store different types of Drupal data in MongoDB.
>
> Views integration provided by [EntityFieldQuery Views Backend](https://www.drupal.org/project/efq_views).